# Run functions only after animate.css removeClass transition finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

[animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

I don't know how to put this but I have code similar to this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/imsy041/5cm2cg0L/)

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $('#test1').addClass('animated infinite pulse tada');
    $('#test2').addClass('animated infinite pulse tada');
    $('#test3').addClass('animated infinite pulse tada');
});

$("#btn2").click(function(){
    $('button').removeClass('animated infinite pulse tada');
    $('#test1').addClass('animated infinite pulse tada');
    $('#test2').addClass('animated infinite pulse tada');
    $('#test3').addClass('animated infinite pulse tada');
    $('#test5').addClass('animated infinite pulse tada');
});
```

Why is it that the animation become disorder if I click button 2 after button 1? Is it because when executing the removeClass it also has transition speed? If so how do I make it to only addClass after the transition has completely stopped? Or at least stop the animation instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animation tooks almost 50milliseconds to complete. you are trying to remove and add the animation class in the same button click event. What I am trying to explain is that if you removed the class from the button element, actually animation is not stopped. It tooks time to complete the animation.

Solved the issue by setting **setTimeout** after removing the class.

Please check this [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/5cm2cg0L/11/).

Comment: yes this works, but is this the only way? thanks anyway

Comment: this is not a good solution for many many reasons, setTimeout doesnt necessarly fire on that exact time, only a minimum of the time specified. also you need to change the code in two places if you change the duration? this is not robust at all. plus if you dont know another solution, you shouldnt say its the only one, since there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the animation delay for removing class only. Try that CSS:

```
button:not(.animated) {
  animation-delay: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use When [Then in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $('#test1, #test2, #test3').addClass('animated infinite pulse tada');
});

$("#btn2").click(function(){
      $.when(function(){ $('button').removeClass('animated infinite pulse tada');})
     .then(function( x ) {
             $('#test1, #test2, #test3, #test5').addClass('animated infinite pulse tada');
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Updated answer

I updated your fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/5cm2cg0L/14/)

> animationend — fires when an animation ends (attention, never fires
> for infinite animations)

I used an event to detect next animation iteration and remove the animation after its called. afterwards i unbind the event from the same element in order to enable the animation to work back again whenever needed.

```
function removeAnimation(elm) {
  var animationIteration = "animationiteration webkitAnimationIteration oanimationiteration MSAnimationIteration";
  elm.one(animationIteration, function () {
    $(this).unbind(animationIteration).removeClass('animated infinite pulse tada')
  }); 
}
```

Comment: I tried that, cant get it to work. can you show me how to do it on JSFiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/5cm2cg0L/13/